# SpringMVC- Mockito- Junit - NullPointerException when service class method is called from controller class

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am writing a web-application, by using spring MVC . I have made a service class to map things to and from the database using UI.

My problem is I am new to junit and mockito
when i am trying to write unit tests on Controller class, it always returns a NullPointerException. It is really annoying since I am unable to find the answer, so I hope you guys can help me out. Below I have posted my code.

My Controller class method on /update return success

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateFormData(@ModelAttribute CRDetails certGuide,
            ModelMap model) { 
        crService.updateCertification(certGuide);
        return "success";   
}
```

My Service class method updates mongodb with modified data

```
public void updateCertification(CRDetails certGuide) {      String userTypeSubmitted = certGuide.getCertGuidelines().getUserType();         System.out.println("updated by " + userTypeSubmitted);      Update update = new Update();       Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("cr").is("CR1"));

        CRDetails details = certMongoTemplate.findOne(query, CRDetails.class,
                COLLECTION_NAME);       CertificateGuidelines newCertGuide = new CertificateGuidelines();

        if (details != null) {          newCertGuide.setCertG(certGuide.getCertGuidelines().getCertG());            if (userTypeSubmitted.equals("Certification Team")
                    && userTypeSubmitted != "") {
                newCertGuide.setStatus("Pending with Document Developer");          } else {
                newCertGuide.setStatus("Pending with Certification Team");          }           newCertGuide.setHistoryCount(++count);

            // converting it into mongo document.           MongoConverter converter = certMongoTemplate.getConverter();            DBObject newRec = (DBObject) converter
                    .convertToMongoType(newCertGuide);          update.set("certGuidelines", newRec);       }

        System.out.println("new cert guide " + newCertGuide.getCertG() + " "
                + newCertGuide.getStatus() + " "
                + newCertGuide.getHistoryCount() + " "
                + newCertGuide.getUserType());
                certMongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, CRDetails.class); }
```

My controllerTest class which return `NullPointerException`.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Before; 
import org.junit.Test; 
import org.mockito.InjectMocks; 
import org.mockito.Mock;  
import org.mockito.Mockito; 
import org.springframework.test.web.server.MockMvc; 
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;

import com.cerner.docworks.controller.CRController; 
import com.cerner.docworks.domain.CRDetails; 
import com.cerner.docworks.service.CRService;


public class CRControllerTest  {

    /*@Mock     private CRService service;*/
    @Mock   View mockView;

   @InjectMocks      
   private CRController crController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

     @Before     public void setup() {
             }

    @Test   public void testUpdate() throws Exception {          //     CRService service = Mockito.mock(CRService.class);      CRService crService = Mockito.spy(new CRService());         ModelMap model = Mockito.mock(ModelMap.class);      CRDetails certGuide = Mockito.spy(new CRDetails());
                CRController controller = new CRController();

                 //     Mockito.when(service.updateCertification(certGuide)); //        Mockito.when(model.addAttribute(Matchers.eq("certGuide"),any(String.class))).thenReturn(null); //       Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(crService).updateCertification(certGuide);         Mockito.doNothing().when(crService).updateCertification(certGuide);         Mockito.mockingDetails(certGuide); //       Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(crService).updateCertification(certGuide); //       Mockito.(crService)).updateCertification(certGuide);;       String fileName = controller.updateFormData(certGuide, model);
                System.out.println(fileName); //        Mockito.verify(controller).updateFormData(certGuide, model);        assertEquals("success", fileName);  } }
```

Trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.cerner.docworks.controller.CRController.updateFormData(CRController.java:81)
>     at
>   com.cerner.docworks.controller.test.CRControllerTest.testUpdate(CRControllerTest.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

FYI,
CRDetails is a pojo class with

```
private String id;
    private String cr;
    private String desc;
    private CertificateGuidelines certGuidelines;
    private Date dueDate;
    //private String userType;
    private String solutionName;
```

FYI,
When i am debugging the code, i found mock is setting objects to null
If i do set details manually, test case pass but, i want to use mockito.

Thanks in advance for ur help.

Comment: The better approach is to use constructor injection on your controller. You can use Mockito mocks easily without the need for reflection hacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the test with the [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html), e.g.:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CRControllerTest {
     // ...
```

This allows `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` to work properly. I.e. `mockView` will be created as a mock of `View` and `crController` will be created with relevant `@Mock`-annotated fields.

You can refer to [the documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/index.html?org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) to see how the mocks are injected.